# Why am I getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')` in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, express, google-cloud-firestore

My issue is when a user enters the wrong password (password variable named Key). The message telling them they were unsuccessful is rendered but after a few seconds, an error appears.
Here is the error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')`

Here is the login function that uses Fetch API

```
const contactServer = async () => {
    if (id === "") {
      alert("Please enter an account #");
    }
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ Id: id, Key: key }),
    };
    await fetch("http://10.0.2.2:5000/login", requestOptions)
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.message === "Match Found") {
          signInAnonymously(auth)
            .then(() => {
              setErrorMsg("");
              alert("Success!");
              setIsLoggedIn(true);
              setID(id);
              navigation.navigate("Welcome");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              alert("Try again");
            });
        } else {
          //Snack bar renders on an unsuccessful attempt
          setVisible(true);
          setErrorMsg("The information you entered did not match our records.");
          return;
        }
      });
  };
```

And here is the API it's targeting

```
app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const Id = req.body.Id;
  const Key = req.body.Key;
  
  if (Id === "") {
    return;
  }
  try {
    const accountRef = await db
      .collection("Account")
      .where("ID", "==", Id)
      .get();
    if (accountRef.empty) {
      res.json({ message: "Invalid Account #" });
    } else {
      //==== forEach loop is necessary for data() function =====
      accountRef.forEach(async (doc) => {
        const storedKey = doc.data().Key;
        bcrypt.compare(Key, storedKey, function (err, matches) {
          if (!matches) {
            console.log("Not matching");
// No Match is sent to client
            res.json({message: "No Match"});
          } else if (matches) {
            console.log("Match Found");
            res.json({ message: "Match Found" });
          } else {
            res.json({ message: "Error" });
          }
        });
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

What is causing this error?

**UPDATE**
6-21
I added a setTimeout function to the visible state of the react native snack bar and now no error.

```
const contactServer = async () => {
    if (id === "") {
      alert("Please enter an account #");
    }
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ Id: id, Key: key }),
    };
    await fetch(
      "http://10.0.2.2:5001/vcs-reads/us-central1/app/login",
      requestOptions
    )
      .then((res) => {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res.message === "Match Found") {
          signInAnonymously(auth)
            .then(() => {
              setErrorMsg("");
              alert("Success!");
              setIsLoggedIn(true);
              setID(id);
              navigation.navigate("Welcome");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.error(error);
              alert("Try again");
            });
        } else {
          setVisible(true);
          setErrorMsg("The information you entered did not match our records.");
          setTimeout(() => {
            setVisible(false);
          }, 3000);
          return;
        }
      });
  };
  const URI = "../assets/mountainBackground.jpg";
```

Comment: Verify that the `signInAnonymously` function has been supplied with a correctly initialized `auth` object. Make that the `auth` object is imported properly and has the required authentication methods.